# why would I need to use `memory` in front-of parameter?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

Let's say I have the following contract.

```
contract D {
    
    function again(uint256[] memory bla) public returns(uint) {
        return bla[0];
    }
}
contract A { 
    
   
    
    function test(D f, uint256[] memory haha) public returns(uint) {
        
        return f.again(haha);
        
    }
    
   
}
```

So, we deploy D, then Deploy A ,and call contract D , from contract A via `test` function.

The code seems to be working the same if in the `again` function, we change it from `memory` to `calldata`.

I have seen some places that some still put `memory`.  It seems to me that using `memory` causes more gas due to copy operations. Any idea why I wouldn't use `calldata` and use `memory` ?

Comment: In your example, `calldata` is perfectly fine. However, you can't modify `calldata` arrays. So if you want to do something with `haha` or `bla`, it has to be copied to memory.

Comment: So, basically, what you're referring is if I use the parameter for read-only, I should use `calldata` . If I need to change something in the passed array, then I use `memory` since it has to be copied. right ?

Comment: Sounds about right. There can of course be other case specific needs where you would want to pick memory.